# Looking to create a javascript showing delivery between Date+5days and Date+10days

Tags: javascript

I already show that the delivery is between, for example 5 and 10 workings but I would like to add an extra line after this where it will specify the dates the delivery is expected between. i.e. I would like it to say:

Free Shipping: Between 5 and 10 working days (Your item will be delivered between 21st December and 26th December)

Here is what I have so far, any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

The HTML:

```
<div id="day">
    <li>Free Shipping: (<div id="fsv1" value="5">5</div> to <div id="fsv2" value="10">10</div> working days)</li>
    <li>Express Shipping: (<div id="esv1" value="3">3</div> to <div id="esv2" value="4">4</div> working days)</li>
</div>
<div id="outputFreeShipping"></div>
<div id="outputExpressShipping"></div>
```

The Javascript:

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('fsv1').value;
var b = document.getElementsByTagName('fsv2').value;
var c = document.getElementsByTagName('esv1').value;
var d = document.getElementsByTagName('esv2').value;
var e = new Date(month, day);

var f = document.write("Your item will be delivered between" + a.value + e + "and" + b.value + e);
var g = document.write("Your item will be delivered between" + c.value + e + "and" + d.value + e);

var h = document.getElementById('outputFreeShipping');
h.innerHTML = h.innerHTML + a + b;

var i = document.getElementById('outputExpressShipping');
i.innerHTML = i.innerHTML + c + d;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) which is a date and time manipulation library in javascript.

To get 5 days from now:

```
var in5Days = moment().add("days",5);
```

and to format for view:

```
in5Days.format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY"); // "Sunday, February 14th 2010"
```

Comment: Thank you for this, is the rest of my coding sufficient to make this work?

Comment: I second using moment. Doing this in vanilla Javascript is a pain. You'll need to ordinate, create an array of months, etc...

Comment: No, your code is flawed. But you would have figured this out quickly if you had tried it.  I fixed it with some modification http://jsfiddle.net/rY6TT/